# How do I know eval function result in Error in R

Tags: r

The eval function in R can evaluate one R expression, my question is how can I know whether it would return error when the R expression is invalid. Thanks

Comment: Not much clear to me. What do you mean by "invalid" expression?

Comment: You could use a `try` or `tryCatch` to test it